# Using SUMIFS to sum all rows matching one criteria within a column matched by another criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

I think I'm very close to what I want but I'm still getting an #N/A error -

I have some wage sheets that cross reference a labour table 'Table1' which stores the information of my employees (Pay code, Site, Contracted Hours etc). In Table1 I have columns titled 1-10 which values.

On the wage sheet I have a cell 'AM3' that will be a number between 1-10. Depending on that cell, the cell below should sum up all values in that column for all staff at that particular site.

For example - I have a wage sheet for site 'EXAMPLE SITE' which is stored in cell C2 and cell AM3 = 9.

I am trying to use the following formula to make this work:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Table1,,MATCH(AM3,Table1[#Headers]),0),Table1[[Site]:[Site]],$C$2)
```

That is, I'm checking Table1, and finding the column headed with the value contained in cell AM3 (with an exact match). criteria_range1 is the Site column and criteria1 is 'EXAMPLE SITE' stored in C2.

I would expect this to sum every cell in column header 9, matching Site 'EXAMPLE SITE'. But I just get the #N/A error.

Table1:

```
Name - Site         - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8  - 9  - 10

Tom  - EXAMPLE SITE - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0  - 10 - 20
Geoff- EXAMPLE SITE - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0  - 9  - 18
Sarah- RANDOM SITE  - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 5 - 15 - 25 - 40
```

With that example I want the formula to return '19' as a numerical value. I feel like I'm just being dumb but no amount of googling is helping me.

Comment: Hi, your formula looks overly complicated for the task set, simple SUMIF() should do the work.

Comment: True, but SUMIFS can be updated to add more criteria should I need to, and there's a very good chance of that in the future in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MATCH` seems to be having a hard time with matching table headers with numeric values. Try this:

`=SUMIFS(INDEX(Table1,,MATCH(AM3,INDEX(Table1[#Headers]*1,),0)),Table1[[Site]:[Site]],$C$2)`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with MATCH as earlier but alternate resolution.

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Table1[[1]:[10]],0,MATCH(TEXT(AM3, "0"),Table1[[#Headers],[1]:[10]],0)),Table1[Site],C2)
```

[image]